# JQuery append event to existing event

Tags: jquery

Have some code

```
<a href=# onclick=alert("in onclick")> Click me </a>
```

I want to append an additional event to onclick, e.g. if the user clicks on the link, he gets 2 messages:

1. from standard onclick
2. from jQuery onclick

Comment: What is the problem? Do you want 2 messages or just one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href='#' id='your_link' onclick='alert("in onclick")'> Click me </a>
```

In your javascript :

```
$('#your_link').click(function()
{
  alert('jquery onclick') ;
}) ;
```